# To retrieve a single list item by using current date or todays date

Tags: spfx-webparts

```
  private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {  
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
      var Date = new Date(this.valueOf());
      Date.setDate(Date.getDate() + days);
      return Date;
  }
  var today = new Date();

  var Startdate = today.toISOString().substring(0,10) + "T00:00:00.000Z";
  var Enddate = today.addDays(1).toISOString().substring(0,10) + "T00:00:00.000Z";

var queryString = "&$Top=1 $filter=Today le datetime'" + Enddate + "'and Today ge datetime'" + Startdate + "'";

jQuery.ajax({
  url: encodeURI(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + ThoughtforthedayWebPart + "')/items?" + queryString),
  type: "GET",
  headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  }
}).done(function (data) { console.log(data.d.results})
}
```

Having error in this code. Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in query and in dates, check following code:

```
var Startdate = today.toISOString().substring(0,10) + "T00:00:00.000Z";
var Enddate = today.toISOString().substring(0,10) + "T23:00:00.000Z";
var queryString = "&$Top=1&$filter=Today le datetime'" + Enddate + "' and Today ge datetime'" + Startdate + "'";
```

You missed & before $filter.